# CakePHP routes problems

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.3

I have this strange problem.

I run my project and all works fine except with the paginator option in the next, previous or select number on a record.

```
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->first('<< first');
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->last('last >>');                 
?>
```

it gives me:
**File not found: contabilidad2017\webroot\index.php\cabasientos\index\page:1295**

I dunno why i have /webroot/index.php cz in my browser it should be

**contabilidad2017\webroot\index.php\cabasientos\index\page:1295**
this is my current routes

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/dashboard', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

why is give me that wrong path? how can i solve it ? help me pls.

Comment: Something wrong with your server,  example you have not url rewritnig enabled

Comment: I agree. Please post the relevant .htaccess files and the Apache configuration for that site.